# Detect the Conditional color of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a mail merge from Excel into Word, and I need to copy the background colors of some cells as well as the contents.

Here on SO I've learned that I could add a helper column, and insert a custom function (something like Selection.Interior.Color) that detects the code of the desired cell. I was going to have the mail merge stealthfully pass that code to Word, where a macro would see it and use it to colorize the corresponding table cell.

Unfortunately, Selection.Interior.Color only detects the natural, **underlying** color of the cell, not the conditionally-formatted color.

Is there a way to detect the color as assigned by the conditional formatting?

(There are 35 different columns using at least 8 different sets of conditional rules).

CONCLUSION: These solutions seem to work, but I decided to avoid adding data or macros to the Excel sheet. Instead I put a macro in Word that basically duplicates the Conditional Formatting functionality. It's slow, but I think its ultimately cleaner.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: [`Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814(v=office.14).aspx) but not available before Excel 2010

Comment: @Slai Unfortunaetly, the "DisplayFormat" doesn't work in user-defined functions, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Seems like a real pain. Good guide here: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CFColors.htm

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson Did you check that?  I just tried a very simple UDF, and a non-primary color, and was able to display what seemed an appropriate result.

Comment: You could use an event in Excel to apply the codes, or have your Word code access the workbook and read the cell colours using `DisplayFormat`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I tried it, and it didn't work. That's why I looked it up. Maybe it stopped working by Office 365.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson  Although writing a UDF and placing it on the worksheet doesn't work, you can certainly use a VBA Macro (Sub) to generate the appropriate `DisplayFormat` code and pass it to Word.

Answer (score 1):

As @David said, it seems to be a pain. However, if the conditional formatting includes only the "traditional" standard excel colors (see [here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm)), the following seems to respond properly (not exhaustively tested). Column A (rows 1 to 12) contains values from 1 to 12, and conditional formatting were applied to those cells. The code below seems to work, as long as colors are "standard".

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    For i = 1 To 12
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, that does seem to work. I'll try it in more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a routine which places the displayformat.interior.color code in a "helper column" next to the column being tested.  I also added a column to show the RGB values, but only for interest. Oh, and the colors were all generated by conditional format.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetColor()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
Set R = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(10, 1))
For Each C In R
    C.Offset(0, 1).Value = C.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    C.Offset(0, 2).Value = converttorgb(C.Offset(0, 1).Value)
Next C
End Sub

Function ConvertToRGB(lColor As Long) As String
    Dim H As String
    Dim Red As Integer, Green As Integer, Blue As Integer
    H = Format(Hex(lColor), "@@@@@@")
Red = Val("&H" & Right(H, 2))
Green = Val("&H" & Mid(H, 3, 2))
Blue = Val("&H" & Left(H, 2))

ConvertToRGB = Format(Red, "0\, ") & Format(Green, "0\, ") & Format(Blue, "0")

End Function
```

[image]

Depending on how you are transferring this information to Word, you may not even need to have it on the worksheet.

Comment: Can you tell me a way in which I wouldn't need it on the worksheet? Everything I can think of involves copying it a few cells at a time, and that could be really slow.

Comment: I would have to make too many assumptions to advise.  I suggest, if your question in this thread is answered, to mark one of the responses as the answer.  And then create a new question with your other problem, either here or in  [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  And please post in accord with the Help guidance for [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)