# Increase a value within a cell IF one or more cells in one row are a certain color

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I need to create a statement that will increase a value within a cell by one if one of more cells within another row are a certain color.

I got this, but its just spitting out "TRUE" and not increasing the values-->

```
=OR(D9:N9="RED",$C%9=$C$9,$C$9=$C$9)
```

If I need to create a macro, can someone assist me please?

***EDIT: This is not to COUNT the number of cells with that color associated.***

Please don't refer to COUNTIF statements.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/count-cells-number-with-color-using-vba

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.[Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/) or [Mid-Advanced Tutorials](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/codes-examples-macros-how-tos-most-useful-basics-advanced/) and my [personal favorite](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-tutorial/)
You may give a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530361/detect-the-conditional-color-of-a-cell)

Comment: I am not asking to count the cells with a certain color associated with it.

Comment: The `OR` function in Excel is evaluating a series of expressions and returns TRUE or FALSE based on those expressions. Explicitly, the function only returns TRUE or FALSE and does not have the ability to edit the value of any cell.

Comment: That being said, `TRUE = 1` so if you have a formula like  `= 4 + OR(...)` then the value will be 5 when TRUE and 4 when FALSE.

Comment: "IF one or more cells in one row are a certain color" is basically saying "Count the cells in the row that have a certain color. If the count is greater than or equal to one then..." I'm not sure why you're adamant that you don't need or want to count things.

Comment: =Sheet1!D6 + OR(Sheet2!$E$6:$K$6="RED") Tried this, but it isn't working. Just returns the value of the Sheet1!D6 no matter what color is in the row.

Comment: Probably @Toddleson is because it doesn't work with what I am trying to do. I've already tried.

Comment: Your exact requirements are unclear.  If you want to do this with VBA then how/when should that VBA run? It adds one to a cell for every red cell, but is that "live" (changes whenever the color changes)  or a one-time count?  How are the cells getting colored red?  Are you using conditional formatting?

Comment: My exact requirements are not "unclear"; I didn't say I wanted VBA, I said "if I need to create a macro". I do want it to be live; so if someone decides to change the colors, it will automatically change the number accordingly. The cells are changing because a person will change it. I need the number to automatically account for that change without that person having to change the number as well.

Comment: So you're saying you have a value in a cell (i.e. A1), then if there is a certain color (i.e. red) in another row (row 9) then you want to increment the value in the cell (A1)? A visual would be helpful. You can actually copy and paste grid directly from Excel into SO.

Answer (score 0):

As a proof of concept, I have used the [CountCcolor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/count-cells-number-with-color-using-vba) Function linked to by @TimWilliams, written by Microsoft, to show how you would count colored cells to change the value of a cell in a formula.
[image: Example Sheet Setup]

In this sheet you can see I start with a base value of 1 in Column A. The values are increased by 1 due to the formula in Column B. This increase by 1 can easily be rewritten into any numerical transformation, like a multiplication by a certain constant, or an exponential increase, etc.

The Formula is `=A3 + (CountCcolor(A3:X3,$A$1)>=1)`. With the formula row numbers referencing each cells current row.

In the formula: I use the `CountCcolor` UDF Function to count the cells with a certain color in the given range, which I entered as a row of cells from A to X. I used "A1" as a reference to tell the function what color to look for. The function could be rewritten with a hard-coded `colorindex` number, which would remove the need for an on-sheet reference but limit the function to only work with your hard-coded colors.

Comment: Close; however, I am looking for a consistent increase in the value +1 each time a new row shows an identified yellow.

Comment: Put `=0 + (CountCcolor(A3:X3,$A$1)>=1)` in column Z. Then `=SUM(Z:Z)` will give you an increasing count of rows that currently have some yellow in them.